# django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'bootstrap_field' received some positional argument(s) after some keyword argument(s)

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4, backend

I was trying to modify  my django sign_in template with bootstrap field along with some arguments but i was not able too.

Exception:

```
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\fastparcel\core\templates\sign_in.html, error at line 25

'bootstrap_field' received some positional argument(s) after some keyword argument(s)
{% bootstrap_field form.username show_lable=False placeholder ="Email" %}`
```

Html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% block content%}

<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
    <div class="justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="text-center text-uppercase mb-3">
                        <b>
                            {% if request.GET.next != '/courier/'%}
                            Customer
                            {% else %}
                            Courier
                            {% endif %}
                        </b>

                    </h4>
                    <form action="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {% bootstrap_form_errors form %}
                        {% bootstrap_label "Email" %}
                        {% bootstrap_field form.username show_lable=False  placeholder ="Email" %}
                        {% bootstrap_field field form.password %}
                        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block "> Sign in</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Might just be a typo, `show_lable=False` should be `show_label=False`

Comment: try it but still same error

Comment: Try removing the space after placeholder in `{% bootstrap_field form.username show_lable=False placeholder ="Email" %}` to be like `{% bootstrap_field form.username show_label=False placeholder="Email" %}`

Comment: You're welcome.  When there's a space after the equal, Django doesn't think you're passing a keyword, instead it thinks it is a positional argument, that is, one whose meaning is determined by it's position.  So Django took placeholder to be a positional argument, and because these rely on their position, you always put them before keyword arguments.  Keyword arguments like `key=value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @raphael
and the answer was
removing the space after placeholder in

```
{% bootstrap_field form.username show_lable=False placeholder ="Email" %}
```

to be like

```
{% bootstrap_field form.username show_label=False placeholder="Email" %}
```